# Mercurial Repo: Corruption in most recent commit

Tags: mercurial, repository, corrupt

I believe my most recent commit in Mercurial has become corrupt. I cannot commit anything anymore, nor can I rollback.

I ran `hg verify` which suggested I should run `hg recover`. I then ran `hg recover` as suggested and I am now getting the error:

`abort: index 00manifest.i is corrupted!`

According to this post: http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.mercurial.general/2007-03/msg00099.html I should be able to remove the last 64 bits from the `00manifest.i` file and start working again.

Is this correct and how would I go about doing so?

PS. Everything I have done so far has been on a clone of the original repository.

Many thanks,

Andy

Comment: Fixing `00manifest.i` sounds reasonable. Your linked post includes instructions how to remove the last entry (64 bytes) from `00manifest.i` -- did you try them?

Comment: Hey Oben, I should have mentioned I am on Windows so I cannot do it his way. Are there any apps for Windows that will allow mt to truncate the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can truncate `00manifest.i` using a Python console:

```
$ python
>>> with open("00manifest.i.orig", 'rb') as fp:
...     data = fp.read()
>>> with open("00manifest.i", 'wb') as fp:
...     fp.write(data[:-64])
```

First, the file is read in binary mode. `data` is just a string. Then slicing is used to write back all but the last 64 bytes, again in binary mode.

Comment: And whatever other languages atwright uses, they probably have binary file IO abilities for doing the same.

Comment: The Python option worked perfectly. I then `rollback`-ed the repo and the command line says all is well.